# Is it possible to round values in css? Or, how to solve half/sub-pixels on % translated layouts?

Tags: css, responsive, translate-animation

I have a curious problem. I built a flex/grid fullscreen responsive interface. I used % values. It works fine, but sometimes, randomly, by resizing the window a 1 px line appears between item (horizontal, vertical, or both). I think maybe that's because, using % values and being the elements liquid, the items size is not always perfect-pixel. Look:

[image]

How could I avoid that, still maintaining a responsive layout?

I managed to somewhat good by very little scaling the inner elements (images and rollover layers) like `scale(1.005)`, but still it was not always perfect. The problem is that browsers can't round element sizes on fullscreen layouts, or something like that, don't know.

Just a little abstraction of my original code, just to add context. It's a 3 cols flex layout where 1 col is 50% width (the third one is off screen > the overall behaves like a 3 panels 'slideshow'). The second column, itself contains the grid on the picture:

```
/* HTML */

<div class="sections-list">
  <div class="section column-1"></div>

  <div class="section column-2">
    <div class="grid">
      <button type="button">a</button>
      <button type="button">b</button>
      <button type="button">c</button>
      <button type="button">d</button>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="section column-3"></div>
</div>


/* SCSS */

.sections-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 100vh;

  translateX(-50%);
}

.section{
  flex-grow:1;
  min-width: 50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.grid{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template:
    "a   b" 50%
    "c   d" 50%
    / 50% 50%;

  button{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: none;
    max-width: none;
    height: auto;

    &:nth-child(1){ grid-area: a; }
    &:nth-child(2){ grid-area: b; }
    &:nth-child(3){ grid-area: c; }
    &:nth-child(4){ grid-area: d; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add JS Fiddle to it, for a better clarification.

Comment: @Joykal, honestly I don't think a js fiddle in this case is of any help, because it lacks of the full context. You have code and a shot above, and also the main reason of the bug. The only thing missing is the answer. Anyway, here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/pcwudrmc/72774/

Comment: In your fiddle, no such gaps occur (Safari 12, MacOS Mojave). Are you sure there isnt potentially a white line in the image you are using? Just so be safe, as small white lines can be invisible at some sizes but visible in other. The solid colors of your fiddle do not show the lines...

Comment: That's what I was saying. The fiddle won't be useful. This is a case of half-pixel rendering problem. Probably due to some `translate` transform. I don't know how to make the browser to use full pixel sizes. Maybe I'll resort to using a little js.

Comment: maybe do nothing, is 1px really an big issue? I don't think so, add some background to hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out the problem was caused by the 50% translation on the main element. That caused half pixels when `window.width` was odd.

The solution to me was to recalculate and round the translation using a little javascript, css --properties and a fallback for legacy browsers. Here's some simplified code (and please look to the original's code too):

```
:root{
  --half-window: -50%;
}

.sections-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 100vh;

  transform: translatex(-50%); // legacy
  transform: translatex(var(--half-window));
}
```

then:

```
function round_half_window(){
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--half-window', -Math.round($(window).width()/2) + 'px');
}

$window.resize(_.debounce(function(){ round_half_window(); },500));
round_half_window();
```